# Check if standard built in object is available

Tags: javascript

I am working on a React.js web app, containing datatable that uses the [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) (internationalization object). The following error only rises when trying to load the application on an old Safari browser.

This is the method currently used to check if `Intl` is available and if not draw back to `localCompare()`

```
function getCollatorComparator() { 
    if (Intl) return new Intl.Collator(void 0, { numeric: !0, sensitivity: "base" }).compare;
    return function(e, t) {
        return (e + "").localeCompare(t) 
    } 
}
```

The above code does not work on legacy Safari (iOS 9).

How can I check if `Intl` is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `if(Intl)` you're going to get an error as `Intl` is not defined, similarly to this:

```js
if(foo) { // foo not defined -> thus crash
  console.log("foo");
} else {
  console.log("bar"); // not executed
}
```

However, if you use `typeof`, you can check if a varaible hasn't been declared before:

```js
if(typeof foo !== "undefined") { // no crash (foo is undefined)
  console.log("foo");
} else {
  console.log("bar"); // bar is outputted
}
```

Thus, instead of using (which throws an error if `Intl` isn't defined):

```
if(Intl) // code...
```

you can use:

```
if(typeof Intl !== "undefined") // code...
```